# Clear Blender BVH Cache

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, cache

A lot of times when I'm rendering in Cycles, I enable BVH caching to speed up my render time. The only downside to doing this is that in scenes with high geometry my hard drive fills up quickly.
Is there some sort of solution to clearing the cache at the end of the render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple add-on that'll clear the BVH cache.
It's a one-click process that works quite nicely! Enjoy!

https://github.com/gbolet/BlenderCacheManager

[image]